# T-SQL: query with print statement within loop returns results inconsistently

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting an unexpected result while trying to use a print statement within a loop.

Here is the loop. Now, I happen to know that there is no data in this table with a createDtTm earlier than June 2012.

I am trying to return nicely formatted results with nulls weeded out in a single pane, hence all the casting and putting returned data into the @text variable for printing.

```
Declare @month int, @day int, @text VARCHAR(max)
Select @month=1
Select @day=1

While @month < 13  Begin
    While @day < 32 Begin
        select @month, @day
        set @text = (SELECT cast(min([createDtTm]) as varchar(50)) + ' | ' +  cast(max([createDtTm]) as varchar(50)) + ' | ' +  cast(DATEDIFF (ss, min([createDtTm]), max([createDtTm])) as varchar(50))
            FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
                where datepart(yy, createDtTm) = 2012
                and datepart(mm, createDtTm) = @month
                and datepart(dd, createDtTm) = @day
                and datepart(hh, createDtTm) > 17
                and cast(Request as varchar(max)) like '%sometext%');
        print @text
        Set @day = @day + 1
        End
    Set @month = @month + 1
    Set @day = 1
End
```

This query returns the results I'd expect.

When I comment out the debug statement

```
select @month, @day
```

I get no results. Doing just the SELECT in the inner loop returns a long, long pane with text like "NULL" and "(1 row affected)", which I'd rather avoid.

Thoughts? I just learned the mechanics of variable setting, PRINT, WHILE, and BEGIN/END statements this morning so I'm glad I'm getting something back at all, but I'd like to understand the apparent inconsistency.

Comment: A `select` statement that doesn't perform an assignment will result in output.  When you comment out your "debug" statement there is nothing left that should output rows.  Use `set nocount on` to suppress the row count messages.  The output from `print` is sent to the Messages (rather than Results) window.

Comment: Just a general rule of thumb for SQL: if you're using a `WHILE` loop, you're probably not taking advantage of SQL's set-based capabilities, and making it harder than it needs to be...

Comment: Michael, can you expand on that?

Comment: Based on Michael's comment above, I found the article here: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches?display=Print) and refactored the query with a group by and order by at the end. It still takes a long time to run but the results are formatted perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
declare @a VARCHAR(max);
declare @b VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @a = '1',@b = '2'

print @a + @b
```

You can't print a select query as print